# How to share same login between multiple websites asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, security

I have multiple websites in different virtual folders on the same server. I created a UserManager Website for an admin to create the user accounts for the websites. I am using aspnet tables and login forms. 
The problem is when I add a login page to another website, the login is successfull but wont redirect them to the Main page of that website because the ApplicationID doesn't exist. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into AD FS authentication. It's basically like a single sign for Active Directory.

If you are using forms authentication in order to authenticate to all applications you should:

1. Make sure to make your cookie is a domain cookie (add a period to the beginning of the cookie name in the forms authentication tag of the web.config file)
2. Add machine key to make sure the applications can decrypt the cookie

Comment: I am using forms authentication, I'll try your suggestion with cookie and machine key and see how that works.

Comment: Do I have to write code to redirect to page? I have searched through many examples but there all different in some way. Do you have a good reference?

Comment: Hi,try to make each application redirect to the main login page

Comment: Do I add a login page to each web application? Each Web Application is in its own virtual directory inculding the AccountManager Web App.

Comment: You don't need to create a login page but you do need to specify forms authentication in the web.config. Instead of a login page just first try redirecting to the main login page through the web.config settings. If you can't do it that way then just redirect on the login page to the main login page.

Comment: I found that SSO [SSO_Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic) is only good for a couple sites, but what if you have 10 or more? I've came accross sever threads that also verified that conclusion as well.

Comment: I stand corrected, SSO is ok for multiple sites on the same domain. So I will be using this method.